# Emulate how EPUBs would look on Nook devices

Tags: ebooks, emulator, epub

I am looking for a tool, preferably to use on Windows PC, to emulate how EPUBs would look on Nook devices.

There is a similar program I've used for Kindle, but I haven't been able to find anything for Nook.